# React Native Android WebView video fullscreen (with rotation)

Tags: android, video, webview, react-native, fullscreen

I've currently implemented a native module for RN in order to be able to play html video inside a webview in fullscreen.

To do that, I simply extend ReactWebViewManager to set a custom setWebChromeClient to the React Native Webview.

```
public class InTeachWebviewModule extends ReactWebViewManager {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RCTInTeachWebview";
    }

    @Override
    protected WebView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        WebView root = super.createViewInstance(reactContext);
        root.setWebChromeClient(new VideoWebChromeClient(reactContext.getCurrentActivity(), root));
        return root;
    }
}
```

And I've a simple CustomChromeClient:

```
public VideoWebChromeClient(Activity activity, WebView webView) {
    mWebView = webView;
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
    if (mVideoView != null) {
        callback.onCustomViewHidden();
        return;
    }

    mVideoView = view;
    mCustomViewCallback = callback;

    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    getRootView().addView(view, FULLSCREEN_LAYOUT_PARAMS);

    ((View)mWebView.getRootView()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
@Override
public void onHideCustomView() {
    if (mVideoView == null) {
        return;
    }
    ((View)mWebView.getRootView()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    getRootView().removeView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView = null;
    mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
}
```

It works great if there is no screen rotation, but as soon as I call `mActivity.setRequestedOrientation()` the `onHideCustomView` is called... It seems that calling `setRequestedOrientation()` refresh the all webview even if in my AndroidManifest I've

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Is there a way to avoid the refresh? Or an other way to rotate the screen? Notice that my app is portrait only except that case.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yep. https://gist.github.com/Crash--/93f796d126501b50d04fc0e411877321

Comment: Great, will give it a shot. Thank you!

Edit: By chance, do you have this implementation in a repo I would be able to see? With the UI Module, etc.?

Comment: I'll try to open source this project pretty soon. Will give you update

Comment: Looking forward to it! Cheers.

Comment: any update on open sourcing

Comment: Just released it, but not tested yet (I've a custom implementation in our project). https://github.com/InTeach/react-native-android-webview-video-fullscreen. We will work on it this week

Comment: Any luck with black screen